# How would you model this in a relational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables: Books, Sagas and Universes.
Books has idSaga as foreign key.
Sagas has idUniverse as foreign key.

All of them are one to Many relationships.

A book can be an installment of a saga and that saga part of a bigger universe; for example: the lord of the rings and the fellowship of the ring is the first installment of the LOTR saga, and the LOTR is in the Legendarium universe.

How should i address a book like The hobbit? it isn't part of any saga but is part of the Legendarium universe.

I don't want to add a new field to the table Books (for the foreign key), it looks like breaking normalization.
Adding a new table and relationships between books and universe looks a bit excesive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to add a new field to the table Books (for the foreign key), it looks like breaking normalization.

This is exactly what I would do. I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks like breaking normalization", but to me this seems ideal because the Book -> Universe relationship could be useful.

For example, let's say you had a new feature where you wanted to count all the books in a given universe. If you don't have a foreign key in the `books` table, you'd have to query the `sagas` table for information that is in no way related to sagas.

By excluding this foreign key, you are limiting your options for using this relationship in the future.

In summary, I would go:

```
Books M:1 Saga
Books M:1 Universe
Saga M:1 Universe
```

I also agree with the other answer that there might be cases where a book could be in multiple universes, but it's up to you to decide if that's allowed or not :)

Answer (score 1):

This breaks some form of logic as proposed if *a* book is “not part of *a* Saga” — or else both Book and Saga would need to imply Universe, yet a Book could imply a different Universe(s) than the Saga it is part of.

*This is core issue is addressed if every Book is part of *a* Saga, even if only a Saga of the single book* (The Hobbit is the only Book in The Hobbit Saga.. currently ;-)).

In the base form this is then the following, as currently described, which *prevents the possibility for such contradictions and allows queries to be written consistently<sup>1</sup>*, regardless of how many Books there are in a Saga.

```
Books M:1 Saga
Saga M:1 Universe
```

Another reason to use this model, of every book being in *a* Saga, is it also works for first-of-Saga books when such has not yet been established (and perhaps subsequent books have not even been planned).

Of course this might be insufficiently flexible (read: too simple) with crossovers such as some comic books, depending on the desired refinement classification.. perhaps it is possible that not all Books in a Saga share the same Universe. And if such oddities are possible, then a Book needs a non-Saga relationship to Universe.

<sup>1</sup> While query complexity can be handled relatively simply with a view, avoiding contradictions adds more complexity to the model. One method would be to require a Book to be part of a Saga *or* a Universe; not both.